# Probability of finding a particle in space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, probability, born-rule

Given a particle whose wave function is square integrable, what is the probability of finding that particle somewhere in space?

Comment: Depends. Does this particle decay? Is it consumed by any reaction?

Comment: That is how the person asked me

Comment: I don't think this is answerable without knowing if we're assuming a stable, isolated particle, after which it's too straightforward. Questions are also expected to show prior research effort and thought, so "That is how the person asked me" just doesn't really sit well with me.

Comment: @orifa: Are you referring to $\int_a^b |\psi|^2 \text dx$?

Comment: @Chair: Yes, if by "somewhere in space", you're referring to all space, then the probably is, of course, $1$. However, the phrase could also mean "somewhere", as in within a specified range.

Comment: Usually you represent it the wavefunction in position space $\psi(x) = \langle x| \psi \rangle$ and take its square after evaluating it at a point, but there are lot more details and requirements usually. Perhaps provide more details and background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability of finding a particle in space is done by deriving it's probability density that is the modulus squared of it's wave function or the quantum amplitude $\psi(r,t)$. 
The probability density over the small density of space say $d^3r$,  must be 1 (the particle is somewhere in that space)

that is $\int(|\psi|^2)d^3r=1$ (It's called the normalization condition)
Knowing the wave function $\psi$ reveals almost every information related to that particle.
Hope it helped.

Comment: It makes a whole lots of sense. Thanks for your contribution. it really helped

Comment: @orifa don't forget the green tick mark :')